# Вставка данных с определением повторов

Tags: mysql, perl

Как лучше сделать на Перл? Нужно вставлять в mysql значения, порции обычно от 1 до 100 строк. Значение поля - UNIQUE, но надо, что б система сообщала, какие она вставила, а какие записи уже там были.

Загонять строки в хеш и гонять по 1 запросу, присваивая значения где 0 где 1? Мне кажется, что это какой-то путь далекий. Может есть что-то поумнее?

Answer (score 1):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare(q{INSERT INTO words (words) VALUES (?)});
      foreach (split /\n/, $words) {
        $sth->execute($words);
        $err .= $dbh->errstr;
      }
```

а далее можно уже посчитать как количество ошибок, так и не вставленных записей;

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!mysql_query("UPDATE ....")) echo "Уже есть";
else echo "Обновлено";
```

Comment: а на Перл?

Comment: Блин, пардон. Ответил автоматом на php, т.к. стема по метке подсветилась, а подсветилась оказывается по mysql. С perl не знаком =)

Answer (score 0):

Селектом выбираешь записи, которые там есть, будешь знать какие были, а дальше инсёрт игнорэ)))

Comment: так и сделал, но потом нашел другой вариант.
сейчас напишу как ответ.